# why does putting a box-shadow move all the letters to the right?

Tags: css, reactjs

When I hover in this items, it moves all the items to the right:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVZiS.jpg

This is my CSS code when the user is on the link:

```
.active {
    background-color: #0c95dc;
    border-radius: 60px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 2px;
}
```

And when someone hovers in the link:

```
.activehover:hover {
    background-color: #0c95dc;
    border-radius: 60px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 5px;
}
```

Here is the className and how it is set up:

```
<a href="" className={router.pathname == "/app/posts" ? styles.active : styles.activehover}>
    <span className={styles.iconSpan}><InboxIcon /></span>
    <Link href="/app/posts">
        <span className={styles.textSpan}>Feedback</span>
    </Link>
</a>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 3):

It's because the left padding is changing from 2px to 5px on hover.
Try to keep the padding as it was in non-active class, by simply updating the `.activehover:hover` class:

```css
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 2px;
```